# Is there any effective difference between the get operator and defineProperty?

Tags: javascript

Is there any real difference between the [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/get) operator:

```
var obj = {
    get prop () {
        //insert code here
    }
};
```

and using [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
var obj;
Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", {
    get: function () {
        //insert code here
    }
}
```

The MDN pages say that compatibility is about the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Object.defineProperty` will default to `enumerable: false` and `configurable: false`, while the object literal getter syntax will default to `enumerable: true` and `configurable: true`. This can be verified with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "prop")`.

This means that in the former case `prop` will show up in `for`-`in` loops and `Object.keys(obj)`, and doing a `delete obj.prop` will fail (noisily in strict mode, silently otherwise). The opposite will be true for the latter case.

Note that `Object.defineProperty` (or `Object.create` or `Object.defineProperties`) will allow you to separately choose the configurability and enumerability of your properties, while the object literal getter syntax will not.